# Certain fields missing from profile when viewing contribution page as anonymous versus logged-in user

Tags: custom-fields, profile, contributions, permissions

I'm including a profile in the configuration of a contribution page to collect information about UK Gift Aid eligibility and the preferences of the donor to sign up to various newsletters.
[image]

The profile itself is shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

The issue I'm encountering is that while the contribution page displays perfectly when viewed as a logged in user, certain fields are missing from the profile when viewed as an anonymous user.

Good case (logged-in user):
[image]

Bad case (anonymous user):
[image]

I presume this is a permissioning issue but can't think specifically what might be causing it. **Any help would be hugely appreciated!**

Comment: Is Anonymous missing the 'CiviCRM: access all custom data' permission?

Comment: Yes, it was! Thank you so much. Really, really appreciate that help. If you post as a question, I'll accept your answer (in case you care about such things).

Comment: Great.  I've posted as an answer as it is more discoverable for others than just being in a comment.  But points are nice too:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access to custom fields is controlled by a separate permission.  You need to grant the `CiviCRM: access all custom data` permission to anonymous users.